# jquery variable giving Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function error

Tags: jquery

The below code was returning the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on its first line. After changing `$(document)` to `jQuery(document)`, the Uncaught error moved to the next line.

I tried `var Electra.swipebox` but that gives `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

I don't how to fix it ...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $Electra.swipebox = (jQuery().swipebox) ? $(".swipebox").swipebox() : null;
});
```

Comment: Sounds like the $ shortcut is not setup for your jQuery. Try also changing `$(".swipebox")` to `jQuery("swipebox")`

Comment: You can pass explicitely `$` to ready handler: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {...});` (or even: `$(document).ready(function($) {...});`) then  `$` will refer to jQuery inside handler. Now, you should firstly search why `$` isn't referring to jQuery. Sounds like `jQuery.noConflict()` is used ***after*** ready handler is bound. Is it a wordpress website?

Comment: Yeah ... that was it. Funny thing is that I did that just before I posted the question and got another error on a different line ... but didn't notice that it was on a different line and thought that it didn't work. Thank you @primehalo

Comment: Yes it is a Wordpress website @A.Wolff ... I m adding an html5 landing page to it as the home page. And it has a lot of jquery :)

Comment: Glad I could help! Wish I would have made it an answer, though, so I could have received some reputation points.

Comment: I upvoted your comment. Don't know how much that helps.